# Convert decimal to minutes and seconds using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, m

I have a column that consist values in seconds, I would like to create a visual which displays minutes and seconds. How do I create a measure that shows the decimal in proper seconds.

[image]

Or is it better to do this with M language in Power Query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this **calculated column**

```
Minutes & Seconds = 
VAR minutes = 
    QUOTIENT('Table'[Seconds], 60)
VAR seconds = 
    MOD('Table'[Seconds], 60)
RETURN
   FORMAT(minutes, "0#") & ":" & FORMAT(seconds, "0#")
```

[image]